# Throwing exceptions without using "new" in Visual C++?

Tags: exception, visual-c++, smart-pointers

I have my own exception in my application. And the moment I throw it like this:

```
throw new CChristianLifeMinistryEntryException(strError);
```

Understandably code analysis triggers this because I have used `new`.

It is suggesting that I use `make_unique` and I am trying to establish if that is the correct way to update this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ exceptions are normally derived from `std::exception` and are thrown by value, and caught by reference. This way you don't need to manage lifetime (don't need to delete some exceptions after handling and not delete others).

Like `throw std::runtime_error(str_error);`.

MFC's approach of throwing reference with `new` predates C++ compiler exception support, so there was a way to throw a pointer exception, but not arbitrary type of exception. It is not recommended for the new code.

There's special smart pointer for exceptions called `exception_ptr`, it is usually needed to transfer exceptions between threads, not to wrap exceptions being thrown.

If you wrap an exception with `unique_ptr`, you'll have to catch it wrapped, and this `catch` will not catch derived exception, because different `unique_ptr` and not derived from each other, so wrapping exceptions this way is definitely not a good idea.

Comment: Hhmm. I see. I think at this stage of modernizing my code I will just leave them as they are. Else I'll have to revise the `catch` statements too.